# Linking Java to Neo4J server

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to connect Java to Neo4J for a project. I want to connect an already existing Neo4J database (local) to Java but I have the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/etudiants/helloStackOverflow/workspace/projetnosql/graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:125)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:137)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:130)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:75)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@1a942c18' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider".
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:73)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:68)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:387)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
... 12 more
```

My pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <!-- to be overridden in sub modules -->
    <java-module-name></java-module-name>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <commonslang>3.4</commonslang>
    <commonsio>2.4</commonsio>
    <jackson>2.8.11</jackson>
    <httpclient>4.5.2</httpclient>
    <junit>4.12</junit>
    <assertj>3.8.0</assertj>
    <slf4j>1.7.21</slf4j>
    <logback>1.1.7</logback>
    <mockito>2.2.29</mockito>
    <!-- default for build, if no profiles invoked -->
    <neo4j>3.0.4</neo4j>
    <bolt>1.6.3</bolt>
    <fast.classpath.scanner>2.18.1</fast.classpath.scanner>
    <ogm.properties>ogm-bolt.properties</ogm.properties>
    <neo4j.edition>enterprise</neo4j.edition>
    <spotbugs.plugin.version>3.1.3</spotbugs.plugin.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Compile and Runtime Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${bolt}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commonslang}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commonsio}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Embedded Driver Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cluster</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ha</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-graphdb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.9</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

and my Main.java :

```
import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        File p = new File("/home/etudiants/helloStackOverflow/workspace/projetnosql/graph.db");
        GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(p);
        db.shutdown();

        System.out.println("ça marche!!!!!");
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            // Perform DB operations
            System.out.println("ça marche 2");
            tx.success();
        }
    }
}
```

Apparantly the problem comes from a missing dependency to satisfy the class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.IndexProvider but there kernel-api dependency is specified.

Do you have any idea how I could fix this problem?

Additional informations :

- IDE : Intellij
- Maven : v1.8
- Neo4J : v3.4.9

I hope I provided enough information so you can give me suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Is it correct to `db.shutdown()` before running a `Transaction` on the database?

Comment: Is the Neo4j graph database a Community or Enterprise version? If it is an Enterprise version then for `GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(p);` change `GraphDatabaseFactory` to `EnterpriseGraphDatabaseFactory`.

Comment: Of interest: Neo4j Java Reference - Chapter 4. Using Neo4j embedded in Java applications [4.1.4. Starting and stopping](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-embedded-setup-startstop) - `If you are using the Enterprise Edition of Neo4j in embedded mode, you have to create your database with the EnterpriseGraphDatabaseFactory to enable the Enterprise Edition features.`